# Get only products from xml file where there are no items under that product

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file which has products and items. Products may or may not have items. I want to get only those Products where there is no item.

This is my input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <prod-id>P16753</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <items/>

        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
    <product>

        <prod-id>P16754</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <items>
            <item>
                <item-id>i16754</item-id>
                <item-status>CREATED</item-status>
                <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
                <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
                <content-status>New</content-status>
            </item>
        </items>

        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want my output like this in the xml file. If possible, I want the tags to be removed so that I Can convert into csv file later

```
prod-id P16754
```

I have an xslt code(which I got from this forum) but I am not able to make this work

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


<ns:WhiteList>
  <name>prod-id</name>
 </ns:WhiteList>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=prod-id[not(items/item)]document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: If you want plain text and not XML then using the identity template does not make sense. You say "I want to get only those Products where there is no item", does that mean you want to select the complete `product` elements without `items/item` descendants? Your desired output snippet contains only one element `prod-id P16754` and not the complete `product` so please explain in more detail which data you want to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="products/product[not(items/item)]/prod-id/concat(local-name(), ' ', .)" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

then for your input sample the output is

```
prod-id P16753
```

Online sample is at http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LUP.

Comment: ...thanks but it is not working for me. When I am running the xsl flie on xml then I am getting the error: xml document must have a top level element Error. Can you please advise why this should be happening? I searched in Google and it says that it might be due to incorrect xml file but the same xml file works for other xslt files

Comment: I just edited my input file. I had both the product numbers same. I changed first one. Apologies for that Now I want the prod-id P16753 in the output. You might have already understood it and done the right way but I am just making sure.

Comment: @adit, see the edit, I think the answer solves the problem.

Comment: This gives me as long as we are using <prod-id> I get the following output Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/as829162/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp0000.x...

prod-id P16753.                                                                                      But I have xml files with different name replacing prod-id. For example, same xml file with only replacement of <prod-id> to <identifier>. It just gives blank output. I change xslt file also accordingly by replacing 'prod-id' with 'identifier'

Comment: The above comment is for you. Sorry, I think I named someone else by mistake

Comment: As you can see online at http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LUP, the example is working and does not give that error. You will need to explain which software you use that gives that error you have shown. As for using the XSLT with a different input, ask a new question if necessary, providing the different input. We can't solve two problems in one question.

Comment: @I got it working. I don't know why but when I created another file with the same contents then it started producing the results I  was expecting...weird. Thanks for your help